# Do I need to visit the embassy for Saudi transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, saudi-arabia

I am transiting through DMM. The layover is less than 5hr, but my connecting flight is on a different PNR (and different airlines). Just to be safe, I thought I would apply for a transit visa (I hold a valid Schengen visa).

I am using the [official service](https://visa.mofa.gov.sa/) and have filled my application application, but I have not paid the fees yet (because there is no way I can travel to the embassy in the meanwhile). My question is- does the Saudi transit visa require me to travel to the embassy?

Comment: Does the official service website indicate how applicants are required to provide biometrics?

Comment: There are two factors that might affect this. What is your citizenship(s), and do you have hold luggage - if you do, you will probably have to go landside to collect and re-checkin it in. Your destination country might also affect it

Comment: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/ will give an indication if a visa (and COVID certificate) is required. Airlines use a gateway called TIMATIC to access this, so it _should_ be accurate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Saudi transit visa you referred to is a type of visa that allows you go out and discover whatever city you are transiting, it is not meant for air-side transit, which is allowed for any layover less than 12 hrs without any visa.

However, if you hold a passport from one of [these countries](https://visa.visitsaudi.com/), you are eligible for a visa on arrival. Also, if you hold a VALID US, UK or a Schengen visa that has been used at least once (with a stamp as a proof) then you are eligible for the visa on arrival regardless of your nationality.

Comment: Thanks. I checked with the airlines just now and apparently they said the same- that I would be fine (because I hold a valid Schengen visa).

Comment: I confirmed this to be true. I had no issue whatsoever.